# Docker container cannot send log to docker ELK stack

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, logstash, elastic-stack

I deployed ELK stack and another separated docker container of spring boot app.

In the java app, I use the LogstashSocketAppender to send logs to logstash.

1. If the java app running standalone without docker, it works fine.
2. But when it's running as a docker container, the logstash cannot receive logs.

Can anyone help me figure out it?

part of logstash configuration:

```
input {
    udp {
        port => 5000
        type => syslog
        codec => json
    }
}
```

> dcoker port:

```
logstash$ 5000/udp -> 0.0.0.0:5000
springboot$ 8088/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32981
elasticsearch$ 9200/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:9200 9300/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:9300
kibana$ 5601/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:5601
```

Comment: post `docker port`  of all your containers

Comment: @user2915097 posted ports above

Comment: My guess: docker container has its own network interface, say 172.160.0.10, so docker container sends logs to its own 5000 port. I would recommend to research how to send to external ip, that is logstash's ip.

Comment: Let me guess: the given hostname is `localhost`?

Comment: @nurgasemetey I have configed logstash ip in LogstashSocketAppender, still not work

Comment: Can you post spring boot logging configuration?

Answer (score 2):

You can get your container logs by configuring Logstash as follows and running the container whose logs are to be viewed by changing its default log driver to **syslog**.

```
#logstash.conf

input {
  tcp {
    port => 5000
  }
}

output {
  stdout {}
}
```

The below container's logs will reach the logstash and and can be viewed through **stdout**.

```
docker run --log-driver=syslog --log-opt syslog-address=tcp://<logstash-system-ip>:5000 <image>
```